# how to use controls in module wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, module

i want to add combobox items and use any other controls in module but when i try to use my combobox there, is not recognized. In Window Form Application there was no problem, but in a WPF application I do not know now how to do it?

In WinForm App i do in Module.vb something like that

```
 Sub FillComboBox()

        Dim SQLStr As String = "use testowa Select COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'Import')"
        Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQLStr, myConnection)

        Form2.ComboBox7.Items.Add("None")
        Form2.ComboBox3.Items.Add("None")


        Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While Reader.Read()
            Form2.ComboBox1.Items.Add(Reader.Item("COLUMN_NAME"))
            Form2.ComboBox2.Items.Add(Reader.Item("COLUMN_NAME"))
            Form2.ComboBox4.Items.Add(Reader.Item("COLUMN_NAME"))
            Form2.ComboBox5.Items.Add(Reader.Item("COLUMN_NAME"))
            Form2.ComboBox6.Items.Add(Reader.Item("COLUMN_NAME"))
            Form2.ComboBox7.Items.Add(Reader.Item("COLUMN_NAME"))
            Form2.ComboBox3.Items.Add(Reader.Item("COLUMN_NAME"))
        End While

        Reader.Close()


    End Sub
```

Now i need to do the same thing in WPF app.

Please help, these are my first steps in WPF :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- fill a collection (eg. List of string) from your SQL
- set this collection as the ItemsSource for your combobox

thats all

ps: pls read something about binding in wpf. dont try to code your winform style with wpf.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example to show you the pattern:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EmptyWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" MinWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding myList}" />  
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<string> _mylist;
    public List<string> myList
    {
        get
        {
            return _mylist;
        }
        set
        {
            _mylist = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mylist = new List<string>() { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" };
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

If you need to change the collection while the application is running and you would like the combobox to react to the changes, use an ObservableCollection instead of a List.

A good starting point if you never touched WPF is www.wpftutorial.net